# subquery returns more than one row - decode - where clause - Oracle

Tags: oracle, decode, where-clause

```
SELECT *
FROM acr_cash_receipts_v acr
WHERE 1 = 1
      AND acr.receipt_date BETWEEN '01-JAN-19' AND '31-JAN-19'
      AND acr.currency_code IN 
        DECODE( 'NOINR', 'NOINR', ( SELECT currency_code
                                    FROM fnd_currencies
                                    WHERE currency_code <> 'INR'
                                  ),
                          acr.currency_code);
```

in where clause - decode i need to use select clause to get all currencies

Thanks

Comment: This DECODE doesn't make much sense as you're comparing NOINR string to itself which is always true. Sample data might help.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that the `WHERE 1=1` condition is not needed.

The next is that `DECODE('NOINR','NOINR', (SELECT CURRENCY_CODE FROM FND_CURRENCIES WHERE CURRENCY_CODE <> 'INR', ACR.CURRENCY_CODE);` is likely to return multiple rows (a value that is being selected is from a subquery).

What's likely happening is THIS is returning more than one result:

```
SELECT CURRENCY_CODE FROM FND_CURRENCIES WHERE CURRENCY_CODE <> 'INR', ACR.CURRENCY_CODE
```

There is likely more than one `CURRENCY_CODE` that is NOT EQUAL to `'INR'`

Also, could you maybe try this query, and see if it does the same?

```
select * from acr_cash_receipts_v acr where acr.receipt_date between '01-JAN-19' AND '31-JAN-19' and acr.currency_code in DECODE('NOINR','NOINR', (SELECT CURRENCY_CODE FROM FND_CURRENCIES WHERE CURRENCY_CODE <> 'INR'), ACR.CURRENCY_CODE);
```

I changed the location of the CLOSING parenthesis after 'INR' because it seems to be a malformed subselect.

You can also run the subquery directly to see if multiple rows are returned:

```
SELECT CURRENCY_CODE FROM FND_CURRENCIES WHERE CURRENCY_CODE <> 'INR'
```

Without the DB / a sample, I can't run this query myself.

Answer (score 0):

Your query can be reformatted by avoid using `DECODE` to achieve the desired result as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM acr_cash_receipts_v acr
WHERE 1 = 1
      AND acr.receipt_date BETWEEN '01-JAN-19' AND '31-JAN-19'
      AND (acr.currency_code = 'NOINR' 
          OR acr.currency_code IN 
             ( SELECT currency_code
                 FROM fnd_currencies
                WHERE currency_code <> 'INR'));
```

Comment: If this answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.